# Multi-output Random Forest in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest

I'm building a model in R to predict the total number of rushing touchdowns, passing touchdowns, defensive touchdowns, extra points, and field goals in an NFL game given several features. Basically instead of trying to predict the actual score, I want to gather the components that make up the final score (vegas odds, rushing yards, passing yards, turnovers, etc. - everything except the total score itself).

I'm familiar with random forests and other methods of prediction, but I'm a bit lost in building a model that has 5 desired outputs. I know one option would be to run `TotalScore ~ .` and then try to divvy up the `TotalScore` in to its counterparts, but I'm trying to simulate real NFL games so I want the outcomes to be pulled from actual NFL results. And I don't (think I'd) want to predict these 5 variables individually because they aren't independent.

This might not even be a "prediction" problem, I more so just want accurate "real score distributions" to use in a larger game-simulation model.

It's been a while since I built a model in `randomForest` or `glm`, is what I'm trying to do possible and if so could you point me in the right direction to learn more?

Edit:

Another way of thinking of this is for the algorithm to use majority voting to pick the "best" most likely final score based on common characteristics of the predictors. Then in that 1 final game score, I could unpack all the specific scoring information. Any best practices for this?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! I do not see a real theoretical barrier for a multivariate random forest: just split based on some multivariate criteria, right? What software supports this is not clear to me, however.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Dave! After sleeping on it some more I realize I really don't need a multivariate criteria as I'm not actually trying to "predict" more than one thing. I just want to take projected stats, and compare those across thousands of data points to find the closest real-life game. From that 1 gameId, I could then extract the relevant scoring information.

Comment: With that being said, what's the best practice for finding the "closest" datapoint in a random forest, as opposed to taking the mean of the N-closest data points? @Dave

Comment: The usual $\ell_p$ metrics are the first ideas that come to mind. Mahalanobis distance could be a reasonable one, too.

Comment: I think this is the difference between MISO (multivariate input, single output) and MIMO (multivariate input, multivariate output).  There is no necessary relationship between the multiple outputs, they are not part of a multivariate distribution.  I think a wrapper for the individual RF's could do the job.

Comment: Hi @EngrStudent thanks for the reply, I've organized my thoughts/process a lot more since I posted this first questions and I believe I'm on the right track, but would like some feedback. I made a new post, could you please review if you have the time? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/618969/random-forest-variable-importance-as-a-way-to-weight-nearest-neighbor-variables