# Random Forest Variable Importance as a way to weight Nearest Neighbor Variables

Tags: r, random-forest, k-nearest-neighbour

I'm employing a nearest neighbor algorithm to find a real NFL game that is the most similar to my projected stats. Not all statistics have the same predictive-importance when projecting the outcome of an NFL game (e.g. total passing yards will predict the final score more than, say, number of penalties), so I want to weight the variables in my KNN by how well they predict the team's final score.

My thought was to use all of the variables in my KNN to run a random forest to predict final score. From there I could use the Importance values for each variable as weights in the KNN model. I chose a random forest instead of a linear regression because form my understanding I don't need to normalize Node Purity from a random forest whereas I would with a linear regression.

Where I'm stuck with is how *exactly* to use those weights. Can I just multiply the raw importance values after normalizing the variables in the KNN? Example code of my process with made up data:

```
library(randomForest)
library(dplyr)
library(class)

# Make dummy dataset of real game statistics
set.seed(123)
passingYds <- c(330, 320, 325, 315, 280, 265, 275, 300, 250, 260)
rushingYds <- c(125, 85, 120, 115, 145, 120, 145, 65, 100, 115)
penalties <- sample(1:4, 10, replace = TRUE)
finalScore <- c(35, 17, 28, 25, 24, 12, 23, 14, 7, 21)
gameID <- 1:10
gameStats <- data.frame(gameID, passingYds, rushingYds, penalties, finalScore, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
# Dummy "Projected" Statistics
testData <- data.frame(passingYds = 320, rushingYds = 95, penalties = 2, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Run random forest on finalScore to get each variable's importance on the finalScore
rf <- randomForest(finalScore~passingYds + rushingYds + penalties, data = gameStats)
VariableImportance <- c(rf$importance)

### START KNN MODEL
# Function to normalize data for KNN model
normalize <- function(newdataf, dataf){
  normalizeddataf <- newdataf 
  for (n in names(newdataf)){
    normalizeddataf[,n] <-  
      (newdataf[,n] - min(dataf[,n])) /  (max(dataf[,n]) -  min(dataf[,n]))
  } 
  return(normalizeddataf)
}

# Normalize data for KNN
trainNFLknn <- gameStats %>% select(-gameID, -finalScore) %>% normalize(., gameStats)
testNFLknn <- testData %>% normalize(., gameStats)


### WEIGHT THE NORMALIZED DATA BY VARIABLE IMPORTANCE ###
trainNFLknn_weighted <- trainNFLknn
testNFLknn_weighted <- testNFLknn
for(i in 1:ncol(trainNFLknn)) trainNFLknn_weighted[,i] <- trainNFLknn_weighted[,i]*VariableImportance[i]
for(i in 1:ncol(testNFLknn)) testNFLknn_weighted[,i] <- testNFLknn_weighted[,i]*VariableImportance[i]

# change GameID to factor, and find the game that most closely resemples testData projected stats
cl <- factor(gameStats$gameID)
predClass <- as.character(class::knn1(trainNFLknn, testNFLknn, cl))
predClass_weighted <- as.character(class::knn1(trainNFLknn_weighted, testNFLknn_weighted, cl))

# Get unweighted and weighted predictions of which game most closely resembles projections
gameStats %>% filter(gameID == predClass)
gameStats %>% filter(gameID == predClass_weighted)
```

My projected data of `passingYds = 320`, `rushingYds=95`, and `penalties=2` results in an unweighted KNN selection of `gameID=4`, whereas the weighted prediction is `gameID=2`. `gameID=2` is a **much** more reasonable selection than `gameID=4` based on the eye-test which leads me to believe that I'm on the right track. But I wanted to confirm that what I'm doing is "best practice", could anyone give me some feedback?

Comment: Be aware that kNN is sensitive to feature scale differences, whereas RandomForest is not. That might make it incomplete for using it to weight kNN

Comment: Also, there are some biases in standard RandomForest for feature importance. Ref: https://explained.ai/rf-importance/

Comment: @JonNordby thanks for the reference, I'll give this a look

Comment: Btw, one of the most established weighted KNN approaches is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_margin_nearest_neighbor

Comment: I like to think of it as a scaled variation on Mahalanobis distance.  It is informative about importance, but isn't the same thing as a Euclidean distance.  Using those weights in a discriminator is known to improve classification performance, so its not a bad idea.  Jon is right, its not distance and scales are important.  Many half-way modern RF tools already account for their bias.  Check out h2o.ai if you want an example of that.